# Create a frontend log of status with Prometheus HTTP API

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm working as a front-end on a project, and I have a live json data from Prometheus, with a timestamp and a value (0 to 2)

```
{
  metric: {
  __name__: "somestatus",
  ...
},
  value: [
    1613742412.367,
    "0"
  ]
},
```

I need to create a log of previous status by day, and i'd like to detect when the value changes from 0 to 1 or 2, and when it comes back to 0.

**For example :**
The 18th february 2021, the status value went to 2 at *timestamp* and comeback to 0 at *timestamp*.
=> and repeat for each occurences on a day

I checked prometheus documentation, but the only way I found was to check at short intervals the status, and to have an approximative start and end. It gives me a lot of data that I don't need, since i'll display only the date of start and end of the status.
I may need to logs months of data, which would lead on too much data in the json, especially for a frontend app

```
/query_range?query=max_over_time(mystatus[1d])&start=2021-01-01T00:00:00.781Z&end=2021-01-14T00:00:00.781Z&step=86400
```

This query would tell me if the value reached 1 or 2 for a day, but not at which time, how many times,...

I also found the way to only fetch the **value > 0**. It reduce the amount of data, but doesn't resolve the issue of the start/end timestamp.

**Is there a way with a prometheus HTTP fetch to do this, for frontend application (light) ?**

Note : I can't edit the prometheus itself

Edit : the closest way I found so far :

```
9090/api/v1/query_range?query=sum by(...)(__name__="mystatus")>0&start=2021-01-05T00:00:00.781Z&end=2021-01-06T00:00:00.781Z&step=300
```

Which for a day would give me all the status > 0 with a 5 min interval.
But as said, it's already too much data

Thanks !

Comment: I think  you might need to look at grafana which uses data from prometheus. You can set up an alert in grafana for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll check this out